# Parsing IEEE754 Double-Precision floats in Pure Lua?

Tags: floating-point, lua, bit-manipulation, ieee-754

I have fixed size array of doubles encoded in IEEE754 format, can anyone point me to any Lua code that can do something related?

**Update:** I can't post this question because it's too short, so here's some code I wrote in process of figuring this out — this converts binary string into string of bits like `"0011000"`

```
-- get string of bits for given byte
function byte2bits(i)
   local result=""
   for c=1,8 do
      nextByte = i % 2
      i = (i - nextByte)/2
      result = result .. nextByte
   end
   return string.reverse(result)
end

-- get a string of bits from string of bytes
function str2bits(s)
   result=''
   for i = 1, string.len(s) do
      --print(string.byte(s, i))
      result=result .. byte2bits(string.byte(s,i))
   end
   return result
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that needs this? Lua isn't a low-level language; this isn't the sort of thing that you should need to do in Lua. If you're trying to parse some binary file, that would be better done with some helper C or C++ code that can read integers/floats/etc from the file.

Comment: This is for a component of an infrastructure which only supports Lua extensions.

Comment: Can you describe the items in your array a bit better? "array of doubles encoded in IEEE754 format" is not clear enough. Do you have an array of strings, then? Please include an example of the array you want to parse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [packing IEEE754 single-precision floating-point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14416734/2712809)?

Answer (score 1):

I actually needed to do this and came here for an answer. Doesn't look like anyone has done this before, so I ended up making something myself. I've not tested every case exhaustively, but it's able to reliably encode and decode numbers correctly, with no error between the input and output numbers.

The functions I wrote work with binary strings, but anyone who needs this should be able to easily adapt it for their own uses.

Here's my code:

```
--Define some commonly used constants here so we don't have to do this at runtime
--ln(2), used for change of base down the line
local log2 = math.log(2)

--Used to convert the fraction into a (very large) integer
local pow2to52 = math.pow(2,52)

--Used for bit-shifting
local f08 = math.pow(2, 8)
local f16 = math.pow(2,16)
local f24 = math.pow(2,24)
local f32 = math.pow(2,32)
local f40 = math.pow(2,40)
local f48 = math.pow(2,48)

function encodeDouble(number)
    --IEEE double-precision floating point number
    --Specification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

    --Separate out the sign, exponent and fraction
    local sign      = number < 0 and 1 or 0
    local exponent  = math.ceil(math.log(math.abs(number))/log2) - 1
    local fraction  = math.abs(number)/math.pow(2,exponent) - 1

    --Make sure the exponent stays in range - allowed values are -1023 through 1024
    if (exponent < -1023) then 
        --We allow this case for subnormal numbers and just clamp the exponent and re-calculate the fraction
        --without the offset of 1
        exponent = -1023
        fraction = math.abs(number)/math.pow(2,exponent)
    elseif (exponent > 1024) then
        --If the exponent ever goes above this value, something went horribly wrong and we should probably stop
        error("Exponent out of range: " .. exponent)
    end

    --Handle special cases
    if (number == 0) then
        --Zero
        exponent = -1023
        fraction = 0
    elseif (math.abs(number) == math.huge) then
        --Infinity
        exponent = 1024
        fraction = 0
    elseif (number ~= number) then
        --NaN
        exponent = 1024
        fraction = (pow2to52-1)/pow2to52
    end

    --Prepare the values for encoding
    local expOut = exponent + 1023                                  --The exponent is an 11 bit offset-binary
    local fractionOut = fraction * pow2to52                         --The fraction is 52 bit, so multiplying it by 2^52 will give us an integer


    --Combine the values into 8 bytes and return the result
    return char(
            128*sign + math.floor(expOut/16),                       --Byte 0: Sign and then shift exponent down by 4 bit
            (expOut%16)*16 + math.floor(fractionOut/f48),           --Byte 1: Shift fraction up by 4 to give most significant bits, and fraction down by 48
            math.floor(fractionOut/f40)%256,                        --Byte 2: Shift fraction down 40 bit
            math.floor(fractionOut/f32)%256,                        --Byte 3: Shift fraction down 32 bit
            math.floor(fractionOut/f24)%256,                        --Byte 4: Shift fraction down 24 bit
            math.floor(fractionOut/f16)%256,                        --Byte 5: Shift fraction down 16 bit
            math.floor(fractionOut/f08)%256,                        --Byte 6: Shift fraction down 8 bit
            math.floor(fractionOut % 256)                           --Byte 7: Last 8 bits of the fraction
        )
end

function decodeDouble(str)
    --Get bytes from the string
    local byte0 = byte(substr(str,1,1))
    local byte1 = byte(substr(str,2,2))
    local byte2 = byte(substr(str,3,3))
    local byte3 = byte(substr(str,4,4))
    local byte4 = byte(substr(str,5,5))
    local byte5 = byte(substr(str,6,6))
    local byte6 = byte(substr(str,7,7))
    local byte7 = byte(substr(str,8,8))

    --Separate out the values
    local sign = byte0 >= 128 and 1 or 0
    local exponent = (byte0%128)*16 + math.floor(byte1/16)
    local fraction = (byte1%16)*f48 
                     + byte2*f40 + byte3*f32 + byte4*f24 
                     + byte5*f16 + byte6*f08 + byte7

    --Handle special cases
    if (exponent == 2047) then
        --Infinities
        if (fraction == 0) then return math.pow(-1,sign) * math.huge end

        --NaN
        if (fraction == pow2to52-1) then return 0/0 end
    end

    --Combine the values and return the result
    if (exponent == 0) then
        --Handle subnormal numbers
        return math.pow(-1,sign) * math.pow(2,exponent-1023) * (fraction/pow2to52)
    else
        --Handle normal numbers
        return math.pow(-1,sign) * math.pow(2,exponent-1023) * (fraction/pow2to52 + 1)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After 8 years the landscape has fortunately changed:

A still being updated pure lua library that closely resembles other struct libraries exists here: https://luarocks.org/modules/deepakjois/vstruct

Among other formats it can parse both floats and doubles in any endianess.

Example:

```
local readfloat = vstruct.compile("f4") -- compile a parser, f4 is a 4 byte float
local results = {}
readfloat:read("aaaa",results) -- can return either a new table or reuse one as done here
print(results[1]) -- 2.5984589414244e+20
```