# Lua - packing IEEE754 single-precision floating-point numbers

Tags: floating-point, lua, ieee-754, pack

I want to make a function in pure Lua that generates a **fraction** (23 bits), an **exponent** (8 bits), and a **sign** (1 bit) from a number, so that the number is approximately equal to `math.ldexp(fraction, exponent - 127) * (sign == 1 and -1 or 1)`, and then packs the generated values into 32 bits.

A certain function in the math library caught my attention:

> The frexp function breaks down the floating-point value (v) into a mantissa (m) and an exponent (n), such that the absolute value of m is greater than or equal to 0.5 and less than 1.0, and v = m * 2^n.
>
> Note that math.ldexp is the inverse operation.

However, I can't think of any way to pack non-integer numbers properly. As the the mantissa returned by this function is not an integer, I'm not sure if I can use it.

Is there any efficient way to do something similar to `math.frexp()` which returns an integer as the mantissa? Or is there perhaps a better way to pack numbers in the IEEE754 single-precision floating-point format in Lua?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

I hereby present the (hopefully) final version of the functions I made:

```
function PackIEEE754(number)
    if number == 0 then
        return string.char(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
    elseif number ~= number then
        return string.char(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
    else
        local sign = 0x00
        if number < 0 then
            sign = 0x80
            number = -number
        end
        local mantissa, exponent = math.frexp(number)
        exponent = exponent + 0x7F
        if exponent <= 0 then
            mantissa = math.ldexp(mantissa, exponent - 1)
            exponent = 0
        elseif exponent > 0 then
            if exponent >= 0xFF then
                return string.char(sign + 0x7F, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00)
            elseif exponent == 1 then
                exponent = 0
            else
                mantissa = mantissa * 2 - 1
                exponent = exponent - 1
            end
        end
        mantissa = math.floor(math.ldexp(mantissa, 23) + 0.5)
        return string.char(
                sign + math.floor(exponent / 2),
                (exponent % 2) * 0x80 + math.floor(mantissa / 0x10000),
                math.floor(mantissa / 0x100) % 0x100,
                mantissa % 0x100)
    end
end
function UnpackIEEE754(packed)
    local b1, b2, b3, b4 = string.byte(packed, 1, 4)
    local exponent = (b1 % 0x80) * 0x02 + math.floor(b2 / 0x80)
    local mantissa = math.ldexp(((b2 % 0x80) * 0x100 + b3) * 0x100 + b4, -23)
    if exponent == 0xFF then
        if mantissa > 0 then
            return 0 / 0
        else
            mantissa = math.huge
            exponent = 0x7F
        end
    elseif exponent > 0 then
        mantissa = mantissa + 1
    else
        exponent = exponent + 1
    end
    if b1 >= 0x80 then
        mantissa = -mantissa
    end
    return math.ldexp(mantissa, exponent - 0x7F)
end
```

I improved the way to utilise the implicit bit and added proper support for special values such as NaN and infinity. I based the formatting on that of the script catwell linked to.

I thank both of you for your great advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply the significand you get from `math.frexp()` by 2^24, and subtract 24 from the exponent to compensate.  Now the significand is an integer.  Note that the significand is **24** bits, not 23 (you need to account for the implicit bit in the IEEE-754 encoding).

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [this](https://github.com/fperrad/lua-MessagePack/blob/master/src/MessagePack.lua#L320)?

I think it does what you want in a slighty simpler way.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked it. The method it uses is very similar to that of mine, but uses cleaner formatting. However, there are a few problems with it (it doesn't seem to support zero or very small numbers), so I'm making my own version based on it. I'll update my post when it's done.